# How to create a sign logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, print-design, logo

I was asked to create a logo like this, in the image below:
[image]

I guess it's called a sign logo.

I was only requested to do the design.

I created logos for digital use before, but I didn't create a logo of this type before.

So my question is, is the whole process of creating a sign logo the same as the digital?
Only
you have to use CMYK instead of RGB?
And can you use Photoshop? Or you have to use illustrator?

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sign writers generally require vectors for logos/logo-text The signs will likely have to be cut out and manufactured, and they'll need vector outlines to do that. Speak to your sign writing company. They should be able to tell you exactly what you need to provide them with.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, sign makers will require a vector file to create the sign from. I'd suggest talking to the company that will be producing the sign and ask what or how they would require the artwork to be provided.

If you or your client are unsure of who will be making the sign, I'd produce the graphic in a vector format and save the final file in a couple different formats (eps | pdf | svg) for the client to give to their sign company. I would include information such as Pantone swatches to reference for the colour and also make sure all text is outlined.

I'd also let the client know that if any changes are required to the artwork, that those change requests come back to me as the designer to change. *(Some)* Sign guys have a bad habit of just changing things without regard to the original intent. It's best to handle all changes yourself if possible.